# Unexpected behavior parsing recvfrom() message from UDP socket

Tags: c, gdb, printf, buffer, recvfrom

Currently working with UDP socket, I am stucked trying to understand the following situation.

A reception buffer has been defined as follow:

```
char buf[1024];
...
memset(&buf, 0, sizeof(buf));
```

& is fullfilled by invoking recvfrom()

```
size = recvfrom(sockdf, buf, sizeof(buf), MSG_WAITALL, (struct sockaddr *) &rx, (socklen_t *)&len);
```

I am getting these data from remote, confirmed using Wireshark:

```
01 fe 00 04 00 00 00 21 53 53 53 5f 54 54 54 54 5f 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 10 fe 00 10 02 ac ca fe 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

Using a simple `for` loop to identify buffer content, I get :

```
for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    printf("buf[%d] = 0x%x", i, buf[i]);
}

buf[0] = 0x1
buf[1] = 0xfffffffe
buf[2] = 0x0
buf[3] = 0x4
buf[4] = 0x0
buf[5] = 0x0
buf[6] = 0x0
buf[7] = 0x21
buf[8] = 0x53
buf[9] = 0x53
buf[10] = 0x53
buf[11] = 0x5f
buf[12] = 0x54
buf[13] = 0x54
buf[14] = 0x54
buf[15] = 0x54
buf[16] = 0x5f
buf[17] = 0x30
buf[18] = 0x31
buf[19] = 0x32
buf[20] = 0x33
buf[21] = 0x34
buf[22] = 0x35
buf[23] = 0x36
buf[24] = 0x37
buf[25] = 0x10
buf[26] = 0xfffffffe
buf[27] = 0x0
buf[28] = 0x10
buf[29] = 0x2
buf[30] = 0xffffffac
buf[31] = 0xffffffca
buf[32] = 0xfffffffe
buf[33] = 0x0
buf[34] = 0x0
buf[35] = 0x0
buf[36] = 0x0
buf[37] = 0x0
buf[38] = 0x0
buf[39] = 0x0
buf[40] = 0x0
```

I certainly misunderstood something trying to get/parse received message, but I cannot explain why
printing buf[1], buf[26], buf[30], buf[31] and buf[32] return extra FF ?

Same behavior using gdb

```
(gdb) p/x buf[26]
$3 = 0xfe
(gdb) call printf("0x%x\n", buf[26])        
0xfffffffe
$4 = 11
```

Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: regarding; `memset(&buf, 0, sizeof(buf));`  This should cause the compiler to output a warning message.  Suggest: `memset(buf, 0, sizeof(buf));` Notice no `&`.  A bare array reference degrades to the address of the first byte of the array.  So no need (and should not) ask for the address of the array.

Comment: regarding; `01 fe ...` the `fe` is a negative character.  With the usual sign extension, this prints as `0xfffffffe`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's called *sign extension* and happens when signed values smaller than `int` are [*promoted*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Integer_promotions) (for example when used as argument to e.g. `printf`).

One simply way of avoiding that is to use `unsigned char` (or `uint8_t`) instead of `char` for the array:

```
uint8_t buf[1024];
```

Or by using the `hh` prefix in the [`printf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) format:

```
printf("buf[%d] = 0x%hhx", i, buf[i]);
```